# Codeigniter url handling

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I am working with Codeigniter PHP project. I want the URLs changed to another format.

**Current Format**

`http://localhost/en20/main/my_video/8/3`

**Expected Format**

`http://localhost/en20/my_video/dafaasdfw434sdafdsf`

my current .htaccess file look like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|system|asset|xsomo)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I just want to be unchanged the .htacces and if it can be done by routing.Please can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define js function for using site_url like,

```
function site_url(path){
    path = typeof path !== 'undefined' ? path : '';

    if(window.location.host=='localhost' || window.location.host=='host_name')
    var site_url = (path != '') ? "http://"+window.location.host+"/project_name/index.php/"+path : "http://"+window.location.host+"/project_name/index.php";
    else
        var site_url = (path != '') ? window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/index.php/'+path : window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/index.php';

    return site_url;
}
```

Comment: No I actually want it to do by routing or htaccess. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the config folder inside your application. Open the file named routes.php

Inside routes.php add this line:

```
$route['my_video/dafaasdfw434sdafdsf'] = '/main/my_video/8/3';
```

Hope it helps.